# Entity Framework. Load list of child elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a Trip table. Every Trip has many Bids.
I want to get list of Bids for some Trips.

PSEUDO CODE FOR EXAMPLE

```
var user = contex.Users.FirstOrDefault();
var trips = user.Trips.ToList<Trip>();
var all_bids_for_user_trips = trips.GetAllBidsForUserTrips().ToList<Bid>;
```

How can I construct query using entity framework? I found `Include()` method but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: How did you use the include method?

Comment: Provide database structure.

Comment: We need more details to help you. Chat "Trip" looks like, that GetAllBidsForUserTrips does etc..

Comment: i'm sorry for so meager description but i thought that everything must be very clear and simple for understanding. my database strucutre was the folowing: Trip was the parent Entity, Bid was the child Entity - contained also Trip Id. I resolve my problem long time ago. And query looks like this: bids = user. Trips. SelectMany(b => b.Bids). OrderByDescending(b => b.CreationDate). SkipWhile(b => b.BidId != model.FromId).Where(b => b.IsAccepted == null).AsQueryable();

Answer (score 0):

```
var user  = context.Users.FirstOrDefault();
var trips = context.Trips.Where(t => t.UserID == user.UserID).Select(t => t.TripID).ToList();
var all_bids_for_user_trips = context.Bids.Where(b => trips.Contains(b.TripID)).ToList();
```

Comment: i'm sorry for so meager description but i thought that everything must be very clear and simple for understanding. my database strucutre was the folowing:  Trip was the parent Entity, Bid was the child Entity - contained also Trip Id. I resolve my problem long time ago. And query looks like this: bids = 
                        user.
                        Trips.
                        SelectMany(b => b.Bids).
                        OrderByDescending(b => b.CreationDate).
                        SkipWhile(b => b.BidId != model.FromId).Where(b => b.IsAccepted == null).AsQueryable();